# Set theory problem about sets that contain at most one element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It is problem 9 in **A.Shen**' book

Consider an equality whose left-hand side and right- hand side contain set variables and operations ∩, ∪, \. Prove that if this equality is false for some sets, then it is false for some sets that contain at most one element.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPV3t.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What were your attempts in solving this problem?

Comment: Just encounter it when reading the book. I guess it is an easy problem but cannot figure out the proof.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting - seems like it sys something about $\Bbb Z_2$-valued homomorphisms of Boolean algebras, sort of. Anyway, I bet the following works. First show this:

> > **Lemma** Fix $x$, and define $f(A)=A\cap\{x\}$ for all $A$. Then $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$, $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ and $f(A\setminus B)=f(A)\setminus f(B)$ for all $A,B$.

Now say the two expressions are $\phi(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ and $\psi(A_1,\dots,A_n)$. Suppose $\phi(A_1,\dots,A_n)\ne\psi(A_1,\dots,A_n)$. Then there exists $x$ with $x\in\phi(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ and $x\notin\psi(A_1,\dots,,A_n)$ (or vice versa). Hence $$\phi((f(A_j))=f(\phi((A_j)))\ne f(\psi((A_j)))=\psi((f(A_j)).$$

Comment: Thank you for this nice proof.